# React Native App Not Installed Error

Tags: android, react-native

I'm testing out react native and can run the dev server fine on an emulator. When I go to build the apk to test on a real device, I get an

> Application not installed error

**System**

- My Device is Android 5.1.1
- Emulator is Android 4.4
- React Native 16

**Steps to build apk**

1. `keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-app-key.keystore -alias my-app-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`
2. `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/`
3. `cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease`
4. Got apk `app-release-unsigned.apk`

Is there anything I am missing and is the generated file supposed to be `unsigned.apk` ?

Comment: do you already have a debug version installed?

Comment: No, the debug version is not installed on the device...

Comment: try installing the APK using ADB. ADB should tell you the reason why the app is not is=nstalled

Comment: @VladMatvienko is the apk file supposed to be named app-release-unsigned.apk if it built correctly?

Comment: Did you set up signing in android/app/build.gradle?

Comment: I ran into this yesterday. Follow the steps to building the apk in Android Studio if possible.

Answer (score 4):

This happens due to your app already install for other users so It is not visible in the app drawer. So required to uninstall your for all user and reinstall the app.

1. Go to Device/Android OS Settings
2. Select APPS
3. Your app will be listed here
4. Goto details of your app by Selecting your app from list
5. Tap in tree dot menu at top right corner
6. Press uninstall for all users
7. Try again to install your app
8. Now It will install successfully.

Comment: One way of completely uninstall the app is running ```cd android && gradlew uninstallAll && cd ..```. When I uninstall the app in a Xiaomi Phone it doesn't completely uninstall and I have to run that command.

Comment: the `./gradlew uninstallAll` command solved it for me

Comment: Are there other reasons that can lead to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

For me, the same problem was from insufficient storage space. Maybe it'll help you.

Comment: works for me  but before need disable google protected.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue by just uninstalling the older app by on my device. Seems I had build.apk before releasing my app. So, you cannot build.apk and release.apk of the same app simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

The app was previously installed, after removing that instance the issue gets resolved.